# Capturing an element of a page and saving to file

Tags: screenshot, node-webkit

Is there a way to use `capturePage` in node-webkit to capture just a specific element of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the specific element in pdf format using the [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/). i've never used it but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23775541/2147627) explains it more.